# Colour city in GeoChart Google Chart Tools API

Tags: google-visualization

Can I give a city a colour and show the boundaries of the city, instead of putting a marker on it?

Answer (score 0):

No. To my best knowladge, it is not possible.

With google geochart you can only color regions such as states, provinces, countries or continents. It is not possible to colour specific cities.

What you ask would be a great feature, but unfortunately not available.